# RestTempalete exchange error

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, resttemplate

I am trying to execute this REST api call as shown below using RESTTemplate
When I run this on browser it runs fine 
http://ftc-wbpyrdb201:8080/statdata/InsStatData/_aggrs/getData?avars=%7B%22issuerId%22:19038%7D

But when I use URL in code

```
http://ftc-wbpyrdb201:8080/statdata/InsStatData/_aggrs/getData?avars={"issuerId":19038}
```

code is

```
   requestURI="http://ftc-wbpyrdb201:8080/statdata/InsStatData/_aggrs/getData";
   UriComponentsBuilder builder = 
   UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(requestURI)
            // Add query parameter
            .queryParam("avars","{\"issuerId\":19038}");


    System.out.println(builder.buildAndExpand(requestURI).toUri());
    System.out.println(builder.toUriString());


    ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate
            .exchange(builder.toUriString() , HttpMethod.GET, null,String.class);
```

I am getting below error, Please let me know what could be wrong here.

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 Bad Request
        at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:63) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:700) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:653) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:613) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:531) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you has problem  in the query string of the URL, i used your code to print out the uri

```
System.out.println(builder.toUriString());
```

the printed string was

```
http://ftc-wbpyrdb201:8080/statdata/InsStatData/_aggrs/getData?avars=%7B%22issuerId%22:19038%7D
```

but if you used [w3cschool encoder](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) to encode the same url you will get

```
http://ftc-wbpyrdb201:8080/statdata/InsStatData/_aggrs/getData?avars=%7B%22issuerId%22%3A19038%7D
```

there is a little difference between the two urls, instead of `:` the w3school encoder produce `%3A`